# OutOfMemoryException when accord.dll

Tags: c#, image, image-stitching

I'm using accord.dll to process the images. I've one issue when making image stitching, That is if the image resolution is high and I got the interesting points for one image is 31000, and second image interesting points are 22000. Now I'm trying to correlate those points using CorrelationMatching.match() method at that time it gives an error like outofmemory exception so please suggest me to resolve this.

The following is the code that written in my app is.

```
//// Getting Harris points
HarrisCornersDetector harris = new HarrisCornersDetector(0.04f,700f);
harrisPoints1 = harris.ProcessImage(img1).ToArray();
harrisPoints2 = harris.ProcessImage(img2).ToArray();
CorrelationMatching matcher = new CorrelationMatching(9);

//// Here I got this type of error.

List<IntPoint[]> matches = 
    matcher.Match(img1, img2, harrisPoints1, harrisPoints2).ToList();

// Get the two sets of points
correlationPoints1 = matches[0];
correlationPoints2 = matches[1];
```

Comment: Process smaller images or go 64 bit?